# How to adjust Raspberry Pi 4B's v3 camera to make target full screen by tuning autofocus-window and lens-positiion parameters?

Tags: raspicam

I am using Raspberry pi 4B's v3 camera to record teacher's teaching in classroom. I am using following two command to record h264 images and wav voice:

```
libcamera-vid -t 7200000 -o picture.h264
arecord -d 7200 -D hw:0,0 -f S32_LE -r 16000 -c 2 voice.wav
```

After that, I merge them into mp4 file by ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -i picture.h264 -i voice.wav -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental teacher.mp4
```

I made the screen shot of the video it looks like below:

[image]

How to make the whiteboard in the picture to occupy whole screen by autofocus-window and lens-position parameters?

Comment: does the lens have a zoom function?

Comment: I am using Rasberry Pi Camera Module 3. I do not know the camera has zoom or not. I suppose it has. Since starting from v3, it shall zoom out and zoom in. And this is the reason we select v3, not v2.